# I got "Not in scope SortOn" error message

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Even after I imported the Data.List package, I still get "Not in scope: sortOn" error message. I am using HaskellPlatform 2014.2.0 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this Error message is there because `sortOn` has been introduced in `base-4.8` (see [hackage-base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn)
but haskell-platform 2014.2.0 only includes base-4.7.0.1 (see [haskell-platform-doc](https://www.haskell.org/platform/contents.html))

but you can easily build it on your own with `sortBy` (see @vikingsteve's answer) `compare` and `on` (you need to import `Data.List` for that)

Answer (score 1):

did you mean `sortBy` ?

```
> :t sortBy
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
>
```